# error while packaging electron app using electron-forge that contain sqlite / better-sqlite module

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron, packaging, electron-forge

i'm trying to packaging my app using electron-forge. when i'm running the `npm run make` command the error occure like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7TXw.png), but i have no idea how to solve this problem.

anyway, if necessary, here's my **package.json** and **forge.config.js**

**package.json**

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "better-sqlite3": "^8.4.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "pug": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.1.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.1.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.1.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.1.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.1.1",
    "@types/better-sqlite3": "^7.6.4",
    "electron": "25.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "name": "dishub-admin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Fath Elchaydir Yahya",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "Aplikasi DISHUB BATOLA"
}
```

**forge.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {},
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-zip',
      platforms: ['darwin'],
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-deb',
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/maker-rpm',
      config: {},
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in *webpack.main.config.js* `externals: ["better-sqlite3"]`, that solved the problem for me